# Add an interface to a class that extends another class

Tags: c#, events, class

I have a need to use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on a class.  This is needed to update values in a form when the underlying property changes.

This class already derives from another class which doesn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

this doesn't work:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged { }
```

I'd appreciate ideas on program structure changes or syntax changes that will let me accomplish the objective of updating the form when a property in the base class is changed.

Comment: dude, change your colon to a comma and it will work just fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged { }
```

(Add a comma after the base class)

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just want to do this:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass , INotifyPropertyChanged { }
```

(note the comma instead of the colon)
Hope that helps,

John

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {}
```

Should be:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged {}
```

You will also need to provide an implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged`.